# dd and cat both reporting no space left on device

Tags: partition, hard-disk, dd, cat, cloning

I have a windows 8.1 Pro laptop with a 500GB HD and a 500GB portable USB HD.

I boot up my laptop with a linux live CD so that I can use `dd` or `cat`.

Testing `cat`:

```
cat /dev/sda > /dev/sdc
cat: write error: No space left on device
```

Testing `dd`:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdc bs=4096
dd: error writing L/dev/sdcL: No space left on device
1+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes (0 B) copied. 0.0kB/s
```

When running `fdisk -l` I can see that my laptop HD has been assigned to `/dev/sda` and my external HD to `/dev/sdc`

However `fdisk` shows some unexpected info for the `/dev/sdc` section:

```
fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sdc: 10MiB, 10485768 bytes, 20400 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
...
Device    Boot  Start   End       Blocks    Id  System
/dev/sdc1 * 2048    718847    358400    7   HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdc2   718848  81922047  40601600  7   HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

The `/dev/sdc` external hd shows its only 10MiB in size.

What can I do to correct this issue?

I have tried using `fdisk /dev/sdc` to delete all partitions on the device, but after doing this `cat` and `dd` still return the same error message.

Another thing thats confusing is arn't `cat` and `dd` supposed to clone the source(laptop) hd and copy it to the target(external)? so the fact that my external HD having a different partition setup/config shouldnt matter right? Because the source disk is overwriting whatever is there with itself... Why should its setup make any difference? On a bare metal level the HD is 500GB, I thought that was the purpose of `dd` to clone the Entire Disk byte for byte. If it takes into consideration the setup of the external HD clearly its not cloning byte for byte as its giving authority to the external disk.

## Update

`lsblk` returns

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE   RO TYPE
sda     0:0     0  465.9G  0  disk 
>^sda1  0:1     0  350M    0  part
>^sda2  0:2     0  38.7G   0  part
sdc     8:32    0  465.8G  0  disk
loop0   7:0     0  275.1M  0  loop /livemnt/squashfs
```

`gdisk -l /dev/sdc` returns

```
....
Partition table scan:
MBR: MBR only
BSD: not present
APM: not present
GPT: not present

**********************************
Found invalid GTP and valid MBR; converting MBR to GPT format in memory.
**********************************
...
```

Connecting and dissconnecting the external HD makes the /dev/sdc drive appear and dissappear.

`fdisk -l` is reporting that the disk `/dev/sdc` is only 10MiB.
How can it report this when we have no partitions?

Comment: I agree that leaving aside sectors marked as bad and things like that, `dd` should trash the partition table on your external drive. It shouldn't fail after 0 records either, nor mention `sdc1` in its error message.

Comment: Please post the output of `lsblk` and `gdisk -l /dev/sdc` because it is a bit unclear what is going on.

Comment: Is `/dev/sdc` _really_ your external HD? (If you disconnect your external HD does `/dev/sdc` disappear? If you reconnect it, does `/dev/sdc` reappear?) Remember that because you're booting from a Live CD, the disk devices may not necessarily appear in the order you might expect ordinarily.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz Sorry for the typo, dd doesnt mention *sdc1* in its error, it reports *sdcL*

Comment: @Ned64 I have updated my original post with the results of running your cmds.

Comment: @roaima yes I can confirm */dev/sdc* is the external HD

Comment: What is the exact make/model of your external drive, please? What are the 0x1234:0x1234 values for it from `lsusb`? Can you please add the messages produced by the kernel when you plug it in. I'm wondering if this 10MiB partition contains just a Windows driver, and when you do something "magic" to the device it mounts the true disk partition.

Comment: @roaima I believe this was unexpected behaviour as when I restarted my linux machine the size changed to what was expected. It appeared plugging-unplugging didnt refresh something in the system properly. Another user pointed this out in my other post here http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/296213/how-to-repair-a-500gb-hd-showing-itself-as-only-10mb

Comment: instead of just any old linux live distro, use the one that specialises in cloning disks and partitions, [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/)