# How to repair a 500GB HD showing itself as only 10MB?

Tags: partition, hard-disk, gpt, mbr, parted

I have a 500GB USB HD.

I have been messing around with the `dd` cmd - erasing MBR data, copying my windows internal HD, eleting partitions, etc.

`fdisk -l` returns

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 10MiB, 10485760 bytes, 20480 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 bytes = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk Identifier: 8xb77d52b7

Device    Boot  Start   End         Blocks      Id  System
...    
/dev/sdc1 *     2048    718847      358400      7   HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdc2       718848  81922047    40601600    7   HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

`lsblk` returns

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE   RO TYPE
sda     0:0     0  465.9G  0  disk 
>^sda1  0:1     0  350M    0  part
>^sda2  0:2     0  38.7G   0  part
sdc     8:32    0  465.8G  0  disk
loop0   7:0     0  275.1M  0  loop /livemnt/squashfs
```

`lsblk` shows 465.8G whilst `fdisk -l` shows 10MiB

As the HD is, I can not do much with it...
even cmds such as `dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdc bs=4096` will allow only up to 10MB of data from the `if=` source to the `of=` target...

`cat /dev/sda > /dev/sdc` returns

```
cat: write error: no space left on device
```

I have been going at this for 4 hours with tools like parted, fdisk /dev/sdc, gdisk, is this really that difficult?

There must be a way to just return the HD to its 500GB state...

To confirm that */dev/sdc* is the external HD, I dissconnected/reconnected the USB HD and ran the following

`dmesg | tail` returns

```
[sdc] Attached SCSI disk
```

Comment: @Fox Yes occasionally I have been dissconnecting/reconnecting the USB. Windows currently doesn't see any HD when attaching it...

I could probablly fix this situation using Windows DISKPART, however I am trying to move over and learn linux - something im beginning to think is pointless in all honesty. There seems to be alot of ambiguity from what Im seeing.

I am still trying to find a way to fix this in linux.

Comment: @Fox It is definitely /dev/sdc, your cmd results in *[sdc] Attached SCSI disk*

Comment: @Fox I have done this already and it does effect the Disk, after the cmd successfully execs, running *fdisk -l* will return *Disk /dev/sdc: 512B, 512 bytes, 1 sectors*. This shows no partition tables such as */dev/sdc1, /dev/sdc2* etc Also if I then was to try *dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdc bs=512* the cmd will run upuntil it reaches 10MB of space, even though my internal /dev/sda drive is 500GB with around windows 8.1 OS taking up 30GB of that space...

Comment: What is the brand and type (spinning disk, SSD, or hybrid) of this drive?

Comment: @TimothyMartin It is a samsung S2 500GB portable Hd, I think Spinning Disk - I have had it for 6 years, no bad sectors(can remember running a cmd succesfully on it yesterday when it was being recognised as its 400+GB capacity).

Comment: Have you tried to just reboot, and let the kernel to reread/reattach the device (HDD)? I don't think it has anything to do with the contents of the disk (e.g. partitioning).

Comment: @AndrewMiloradovsky I can try that, but I assumed unplugging and replugging in the device would do that anyway. Il report back in 5 mins

Comment: @Jimbo'sGun's Not necessarily, re-plugging will only work if `udev` & co. manage to update the kernel structures properly (reload kernel modules, etc.)

Comment: @AndrewMiloradovsky Ok it appears now running fdisk -l shows 465GB. It appears plugging-unplugging was the issue... Thanks for the suggestion - perhaps you could put it in an answer, also running *cat /dev/sda > /dev/sdc* shows write activity taking place which has lasted more than 1 min (indicating > 10MB of data written)

Comment: @Jimbo'sGun's Ok :) BTW, instead of `cat` you could better use `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX status=progress`

Comment: @AndrewMiloradovsky I was only using dd/cat and the rest to play(alter) the HD. I am curious if the kernel is supposed to act in the way it did in my circumstance? I would have thought the kernel should refresh/update upon unplugging-plugging devices.

Comment: @Jimbo'sGun's Yes, it should. There are many things the kernel and software and hardware in general are supposed to do, and a certain ways they are supposed to behave. But they commonly fail. \\ I don't know what's happened in your particular case, but the point is that, when something doesn't work as expected, assuming that it's normal, and it's "my fault" for not knowing something elementary, is as much of a mistake as the opposite (calling any unexpected behavior a bug). -- In short: don't assume software/hardware to be perfect, and try elementary and obvious cures first.

Comment: @AndrewMiloradovsky Ok il remember that for next time. Perhaps its worth mentioning I was running my live CD via copying and running from RAM option.

Comment: @Timothy Martin, sometimes fdisk is unable to update the kernels disk infromation table, and re-plugging the drive may not work, you should write up your reboot suggestion as an answer.

Comment: @Jasen Yes, If Andrew hasn't wrote up within a day or so, hopefully somebody else can so I can mark the question as solved - I spent over 6 hours of my time on this issue, it may help somebody save that time...

Answer (score 0):

MBR (aka "Disklabel type: dos") should not mention the disk size directly (nor the number of legacy cylinders/sectors/heads).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record#Sector_layout

Nor should the kernel limit writes to the block device, based on a corrupt MBR on that device.  So either the kernel or hardware was confused.  Worryingly so :).

At a guess, `no space left on device` is generated directly by the kernel.  If the device return an error to the kernel and complained about access beyond the end (happening because the kernel thought it wasn't beyond the end), I suspect the kernel would return a generic IO error instead.  And I'd be surprised if this specific device error wasn't shown in the kernel log (`dmesg`).

The strange thing is that while `lsblk` and `fdisk` use slightly different approaches, AFAICT both are reading a value which is cached in the kernel.  If they consistently get different values, this also sounds like it's the kernel acting buggy.  It's possible `fdisk -l` requests a rescan before reading the value.  However it sounds like you ran `lsblk` after `fdisk -l`, so that difference shouldn't matter.

I would retain a *slight* suspicion of this system.  ("Am I maintaining independent backups of any valuable data, as would be good practice?" suspicious).